# arm_math matrix multiplication hardfault

Tags: c, arm, stm32f4, stm32cubemx

Not sure how to write this, since I'm very new to embedded systems, but I've been trying to code a state-observer for my graduation project and it needs to estimate 3 states on 2 different axis.

The basic equations I'm trying to solve are:

```
x_hat[k+1] = (A-L*C)*x_hat[k]+ B*u + L*y
```

The problem is I'm getting `HardFault_Handler()` when doing the `(A-L*C)*x_hat[k]` part for the second axis.

The code works on one of the axis, but it gets this error on the other.
They don't work separately either.

(Only showing code for the problematic axis)
Interrupt code: (800hz interrupts , dt = 1/800)

```
      placeholder[0]=(int16_t)L3GD20_GetAngularRateY(sensitivity_250,0);
      placeholder[1]=(int16_t)L3GD20_GetAngularRateZ(sensitivity_250,0);
      ydata[1]=placeholder[0]*3.14158/180;
      zdata[1]=placeholder[1]*3.14158/180;
      ydata[0]+=ydata[1]*dt;
      zdata[0]+=zdata[1]*dt;
      status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&Czm, &zdatam, &ZCm);         //C*y(estados)


      status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&ALCzm, &zhatantm, &ALCzantm);  //(A-LC)*yhatant
      status = arm_mat_scale_f32(&Bzm, uz, &Bzuzm);             //By*uy
      status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&Lzm, &ZCm, &Lzcm);             //L*Y(saida);
      status = arm_mat_add_f32(&ALCzantm, &Bzuzm, &ALCBzm);     //(A-LC)*yhatant + By*uy
      status = arm_mat_add_f32(&ALCBzm, &Lzcm, &deltazhatm);    //(A-LC)*yhatant + By*uy + L*Y

      //Integrating to obtain states

      zhat[0] += deltazhat[0]*dt;
      zhat[1] += deltazhat[1]*dt;
      zhat[2] += deltazhat[2]*dt;


      zhatant[0] = zhat[0];
      zhatant[1] = zhat[1];
      zhatant[2] = zhat[2];


      //Generate outputs
      status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&zhatm, &Kzm, &outzm);
      uz = -outz[0];
```

Initializing the matrices:

```
      arm_mat_init_f32(&zdatam, 3, 1, (float32_t *) zdata);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Azm, 3, 3, (float32_t *) Az);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Bzm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) Bz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Czm, 2, 3, (float32_t *) Cz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Kzm, 1, 3, (float32_t *) Kz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Lzm, 3, 2, (float32_t *) Lz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&outzm, 1, 1, (float32_t *) outz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&zhatm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) zhat);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&zhatantm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) zhatant);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&LCzm, 3, 3, (float32_t *) LCz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&ALCzm, 3, 3, (float32_t *) ALCz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&ALCzantm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) ALCzant);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Bzuzm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) Bzuz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&ZCm, 2, 1, (float32_t *) ZC);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&Lzcm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) Lzc);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&ALCBzm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) ALCBz);
      arm_mat_init_f32(&deltazhatm, 3, 1, (float32_t *) deltazhat);
```

```
float32_t ydata[3*1] = {0,0,0};
float32_t zdata[3*1] = {0,0,0};
float32_t placeholder[2*1] = {0,0};
float32_t LCy[3*3];
float32_t LCz[3*3];
float32_t ALCyant[3*1];
float32_t ALCzant[3*1];
float32_t Byuy[3*1];
float32_t Bzuz[3*1];
float32_t YC[2*1];
float32_t ZC[2*1];
float32_t Lyc[3*1];
float32_t Lzc[3*1];
float32_t yhat[3*1];
float32_t zhat[3*1];
float32_t yhatant[3*1];
float32_t zhatant[3*1];
float32_t ALCBy[3*1];
float32_t ALCBz[3*1];
float32_t deltayhat[3*1];
float32_t deltazhat[3*1];
float32_t outy[1*1];
float32_t outz[1*1];
float32_t uy;
float32_t uz;

//Y
const float32_t Ay[3*3] = {0, 1, 0,29.529, 0, 0.17903, -29.529, 0, -29.529};
const float32_t By[3*1] = {0, -3.0396, 4.8226};
const float32_t Cy[3*3] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
const float32_t ALCy[3*3]= {-37.0458, -114.1644, 0, -15.2513, -1535.2383, 0.17903, -3030.1313, -305028.3011, -3030.1313};


//Z
const float32_t Az[3*3] = {0, 1, 0,29.527, 0, 0.17902, -29.527, 0, -29.527};
const float32_t Bz[3*1] = {0, -3.0394, 4.8226};
const float32_t Cz[3*3] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
const float32_t ALCz[3*3]= {-37.4149, -1249.709, 0, -5.5092, -1534.8692, 0.17902, -1140.5251, -330698.2504, -1140.5251};


//system gains
const float32_t Ky[3*1] = {-63.5762, -23.9051, -4.1428};
const float32_t Ly[3*2] = {37.0458, 115.1644, 44.7803, 1535.2383, 3000.6023, 305028.3011};
const float32_t Kz[3*1] = {-63.5806, -23.9066, -4.1424};
const float32_t Lz[3*2] = {37.4149, 1250.709, 35.0362, 1534.8692, 1110.9981, 330698.2504};
```

Comment: In the initialization, are the arrays pointed to by `zdata`, `Az`, etc. long enough to hold rows times columns elements?

Comment: Yes! they are all the same size as declared on the init function
I'll edit the main post with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
    status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&zhatm, &Kzm, &outzm);
```

`zhatm` is a 3x1 matrix and `Kzm` is a 1x3 matrix. When multiplied together, the result is a 3x3 matrix, but the provided `outzm` is a 1x1 matrix.

Perhaps you need to swap the parameters as follows:

```
    status = arm_mat_mult_f32(&Kzm, &zhatm, &outzm);
```

That will produce a 1x1 matrix in `outzm`.

If the hard fault occurs earlier in the code, that might be due to the delayed effect of similar errors.

Comment: That solved it! Weird thing is that the other axis was working almost perfectly and also had a wrong multiplication there. But anyways, thank you for the solution!